# How to add transition to ListView : positionViewAtEnd()/positionViewAtBeginning()

Tags: qt, listview, qml, transition, qtquick2

I need some times to set my `View` of my `ListView` on `lastItem` or `firstItem` ([`positionViewAtEnd()`/`positionViewAtBeginning()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#positionViewAtEnd-method)).

However, it is a **brutal jump** and **I would like to add a `Transition`**.

I tried to add this :

```
Behavior on contentY 
{
    id: contentYAnimation
    PropertyAnimation {duration: 300 }
}
```

But it doesn't change anything. Any suggestion?

Comment: Might be answered [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42530037/2056452). Also possible duplicate of the corresponding question.

Comment: You are right, this is what I want. Thanks !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Animate \`positionViewAtIndex\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42527559/animate-positionviewatindex)